# What to do when installation stuck on creating tables?

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, installation

Upon installation of Joomla the process stops while creating tables. Some tables were created, but not all of them. So far this only happens with MySQL with Joomla 3.x. What should I do?

Comment: Did you check the mysql logs for any error messages?

Answer (score 4):

Installation of Joomla requires a properly configured infra. It looks like several stacks are not properly configured out-of-the-box for this very common Joomla setup.

Increase max_execution_time in php.ini and restart apache untill installation of Joomla succeeds. Installation should continue creating the tables and finish in a timely fashion.

Comment: On w8.1 xampp 181 changed from 30 to 300 and issue resolved

Comment: If that resolves your questions, then please select answer as correct so this question is solved.

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen on my XAMPP on a (rather slow) laptop. Basically the script times out while waiting for MySQL.
Increasing `max_execution_time` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Change the storage engine from InnoDB to MyISAM in installation/sql/mysql/joomla.sql.

See administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates/mysql/3.0.0.sql for ALTER statements to change the engine back to InnoDB after install.

Comment: Please don't. The two work different enough that there might be weird, hard to debug, issues later on. Code that assumes InnoDB might do weird things on MyISAM tables. This is because InnoDB is transaction safe and MyISAM is not.

Comment: If you are editing the sql-files, you can also use phpmyadmin or something to commit the remaining changes manually. It is bit of bother, but not difficult, so it may sometimes be **easier** than changing execution time and trying again.

Comment: Currently Joomla doesn't use transactions. The requirements mention that InnoDB is required. See the update for 3.0.0.sql for changing the engine back.
Advice against messing with phpMyAdmin, there is no reason for installation to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem. Then I found the solution to do some configuration changes in my php.ini file and joomla's mysql file.

The Problem may be occurring because of following reasons -

## 1. PHP timed out.

Look at your `php error log` and it should make this error fairly obvious.

So edit your `php.ini` file, Go to the directory where php is installed and then find the **php.ini** file and find the parameter

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

And change it to

```
max_execution_time = 200
```

Then restart Apache.

Once the install has completed go back and change it back to a value no more than `60`.

## 2. Engine Type

To fix this problem, go to

> Joomla_root\installation\sql\mysql\Joomla.sql

replaced all the occurrence of **ENGINE=InnoDB** with **ENGINE=MyIsam**

MyIsam is more supported and compatible with Joomla.

Do also the same with (sample_data.sql) file, if it's quickstart setup.

Answer (score 0):

You should locate `php.ini` in `C:\xampp\php` or `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`
and change `memory_limit = 512MB` and `max_execution_time=300`
after that you need to go `C:\xampp\htdocs\user\installation\sql\mysql`
then open joomla.sql or something.sql and then find all `ENGINE=InnoDB` and change them to `ENGINE=MyIsam`.

Comment: Why would you use MyIsam instead of InnoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue of hanging of the installation of joomla 3.4.5 on my windows machine.

```
OS: Win 8.1 x64
XAMPP v3.2.1
Joomla: 3.4.5
```

I tried to perform the same 5-6 times. Then, after googling a lot came to conclusion that it can be resolved just my modifying 2 parameters in the php.ini config file usually located inside the

```
<XAMPP_INSTALL_DIR>/php/php.ini

memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 200
```

It worked. So, there is no need to modify the InnoDB engine to MyIsam. Base installation works well. Just the issue with our default settings of the php configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I use XAMPP for Joomla, all I did was to change the `max_execution_time=30` to `max_execution_time=3000`; it worked!

Procedure:

- Go to `C:\xampp\php` and open the `php.ini` file
- Press <kbd>ctr+f</kbd> and type `max_execution_time`, this will locate the syntax line
- Change the value from `=30` to `=300`
- Save `php.ini`

You must restart apache/xampp, and then try the Joomla installation again.

It will work.
Hope that helps.